# Causality and Stationarity in AR Process.

Tags: calculus, statistics, stationary-processes

I am trying to find out whether this AR Process is:

1. Stationary
2. Causal

The process is given as:

$$ X_t=-0,2X_{t-1}+0,48X_{t-2}+Z_t $$

With: 
$$ Z_t:White Noise $$

Solving for $$ X_{1,2}=\frac{-0,2 \pm \sqrt{0,2^2+4*0,48}} {2} $$

I get $$ x_1= 0,6;x_2=-0,8 $$

The absolute values for x1 and x2 are both smaller then 1. This should prove that this process is not causal. How do I now find out if this process is stationary or not?